# RuntimeError: Tensor for argument #3 'mat2' is on CPU, but expected it to be on GPU (while checking arguments for addmm)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, time-series

I have a custom-written model using PyTorch. However, when I try to use `.to(device)` to train in GPU, ı come across this error. The model does run on the CPU but is slow. Can Anyone give me a little insight on how to solve this?

I added the inputs to the GPU as well and still, I receive this error. The second picture added shows the initial part of the error and the title I mentioned in the last lie of the errors.
[Model Train Loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb92U.png)

[Error Initial Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYDPI.png)

```
def build_network(dim_val, dim_attn, input_size, dec_seq_len, output_sequence_length, n_decoder_layers, n_encoder_layers, n_heads):
# Input Size = 1
    t = Transformer(dim_val, dim_attn, input_size ,dec_seq_len,  output_sequence_length, n_decoder_layers, n_encoder_layers, n_heads)
    return t


def build_optimizer(model ,learning_rate):
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), learning_rate)
    return optimizer
```

#### Initialize network

```
t = build_network(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2).to(device)
```

#### Initialize Optimizer

```
optimizer = build_optimizer(t, 0.001)
```

#### MAPE Formula

```
def mape(actual, pred): 
actual, pred = np.array(actual), np.array(pred)
return round(np.mean(np.abs((actual - pred) / actual)) * 100,2)

for e in range(2):
   start_time = time.time()

   # Batch Train Loss
   batch_losses = []
   batch_mape = []

   # Batch Test Loss
   val_batch_loss = []
   val_batch_mape = []

################################################ Train Batch Loop ################################################

   for test_x, test_y in train_loader:  
      X = test_x.to(device)
      Y = test_y.to(device)

      # Zero Grad at start of loop
      optimizer.zero_grad()
      # Forward pass and calculate loss
      net_out = t(X)
      ## Loss MSE
      loss = torch.mean((net_out - Y) ** 2)
      # Train MAPE
      train_mape = mape(np.abs((Y.detach().numpy())), 
      net_out.detach().numpy())
      # Backwards pass
      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()

      # Append the Batch Loss
      batch_losses.append(loss.item())
      # Append the Batch MAPE
      batch_mape.append(train_mape)

################################################ Validation Batch Loop ################################################

   for test_x, test_y in val_loader:  
      X_Test = test_x.to(device)
      Y_Test = test_y.to(device)

      #test_values = torch.from_numpy(Transformer_Xtest)
      val = t(X_Test)

      # Val Loss
      validation_loss = torch.mean((val - Y_Test) ** 2)
      # Append the Batch Loss
      val_batch_loss.append(validation_loss.item())

      # Val MAPE
      validation_mape = mape(np.abs((Y_Test.detach().numpy())), 
      val.detach().numpy())
      # Append the Batch MAPE
      val_batch_mape.append(validation_mape)

   ######## Train Epoch Summary
   epoch_train_loss = round(np.mean(batch_losses), 5)
   epoch_train_mape = round(np.mean(batch_mape), 5)

   ######## Val Epoch Summary
   epoch_val_loss = round(np.mean(val_batch_loss), 5)
   epoch_val_mape = round(np.mean(val_batch_mape), 5)

   show_print = print("Epoch: ", e+1, "epoch_train_loss:", epoch_train_loss, "epoch_train_mape: ", epoch_train_mape, "epoch_val_loss:", epoch_val_loss, "epoch_val_mape:", epoch_val_mape,"--- Elapsed Time Seconds ---", round((time.time() - start_time),  3) )
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: It's likely that you haven't reassigned your variables, the `torch.Tensor.to` function is not in place but instead returns a copy. You have to do something like: `x = x.to(device)`.

Comment: I added the inputs to Cuda as well, let me post a picture

Comment: I edited the post and added some pictures. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide (copy-paste) the code where you are transferring the data to the device?

Comment: I added the code, if you need I can also copy/paste the architecture itself as well....

Comment: Yes, please do.

Comment: The architecture is a bit long, and I could not paste it in the correct format, instead, I am sharing the colab file with you, in there you can find the section dedicated to the architecture only.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lkgX3TQ3bZ_ODE1xYWjB2E_4xhgfcvKr?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you access the file?

Comment: Can you provide the full error backtrace?